# \beamercolorbox location in style file

Tags: beamer

I am designing (actually modifying an existing) style file. I want horizontal bars at the top and the bottom. I can get these on all the pages, but I cannot get the horizontal bar located at the very top of the title page. Here is what I have in the style file that I called `beamerthememystyle` (I have deleted acks at the top to simplify):

```
\mode<presentation>

\RequirePackage{tgpagella}
\RequirePackage{tikz}

\useoutertheme{default}
\useinnertheme{default}
\usefonttheme{serif}

% Puts a line at the foot and also adds slide number
\setbeamertemplate{footline} % show slide number on all slides but the first
{%
  \ifnum\c@framenumber=1
  \else
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.98\paperwidth,right,dp=1ex]{page number}
        \tiny\insertframenumber
     \end{beamercolorbox}
  \fi%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=4pt]{lower separation line foot}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}

% Puts a line at the top
\setbeamertemplate{headline} 
{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=4pt]{upper separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}

% 2. plain title page
\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{DSG-Logo_horiz}}
\usetitlepagetemplate{%
  \leavevmode 
  \hbox{\begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=4pt,wd=\paperwidth]{upper separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}}
  \vfill
  \begin{center}
    \LARGE\structure{\inserttitle}
    \vskip1em\par
    \normalsize\insertauthor\par
    {\small\insertinstitute\par}\par\vskip1em
    \par\vskip2em
    {\scriptsize\insertdate}\par\vskip2em
    \inserttitlegraphic
  \end{center}
  \vfill
}


% Display a slide before the current section with overview inf
\AtBeginSection[]
{%
   \begin{frame}
       \frametitle{Overview}
       \tableofcontents[currentsection,hideothersubsections]
   \end{frame}
}

\definecolor{mycolour}{HTML}{A52A2A}

\setbeamercolor*{item}{fg=mycolour}
\setbeamercolor{itemize subitem}{fg=mycolour}

\setbeamerfont{title like}{shape=\scshape}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{shape=\scshape}
\setbeamerfont{section in head/foot}{shape=\scshape,size=\tiny}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} % hide bottom nav buttons
\setbeamercovered{transparent} % don't hide strip-teased bullet points

\setbeamercolor{upper separation line head}{bg=mycolour} 
\setbeamercolor{upper separation line foot}{bg=mycolour} 

\setbeamercolor{lower separation line head}{bg=mycolour} 
\setbeamercolor{lower separation line foot}{bg=mycolour} 
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=black,bg=white} 
\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=red} 
\setbeamercolor{example text}{fg=black} 
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=black} 
 
\setbeamercolor{palette tertiary}{fg=black,bg=black!10} 
\setbeamercolor{palette quaternary}{fg=black,bg=black!10} 

\mode<all>
```

Originally, I did not have the lines

```
  \leavevmode 
  \hbox{\begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=4pt,wd=\paperwidth]{upper separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}}
```

in the `\usetitlepagetemplate{}` expecting that `\setbeamertemplate{headline}` would do it -- it does but not on the title page. Then I added these lines, but the horizontal bar that it puts is not at the top, but pushed down (I think by the top margin). How can I get the same bar on the title page as I get on the other pages?

Here is a MWE of the test file I used:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{mystyle}

\title[Testing-short]{Testing}
\author{M. Tamer \"Ozsu}
\institute{University of Waterloo}

\begin{document}
  {%
    \setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
    \frame{\titlepage}
  }

  \begin{frame}
   \frametitle{We are testing...}
    It's working!
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that if you use `\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}` to clear the content of the headline, the headline will still have its height.

Two possible solutions:

1. use a `plain` frame for the title, but then you would have to also add the lower line to the title page
2. Not remove the headline. Use this line for your title page and don't add a second one in the title page template

---

```
\mode<presentation>

\RequirePackage{tgpagella}
\RequirePackage{tikz}

\useoutertheme{default}
\useinnertheme{default}
\usefonttheme{serif}

% Puts a line at the foot and also adds slide number
\setbeamertemplate{footline} % show slide number on all slides but the first
{%
  \ifnum\c@framenumber=1
  \else
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.98\paperwidth,right,dp=1ex]{page number}
        \tiny\insertframenumber
     \end{beamercolorbox}
  \fi%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=4pt]{lower separation line foot}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}

% Puts a line at the top
\setbeamertemplate{headline} 
{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=4pt]{upper separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}

% 2. plain title page
\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-image-duck}}
\usetitlepagetemplate{%
  \leavevmode 
%  \hbox{\begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=4pt,wd=\paperwidth]{upper separation line head}
%  \end{beamercolorbox}}
  \vfill
  \begin{center}
    \LARGE\structure{\inserttitle}
    \vskip1em\par
    \normalsize\insertauthor\par
    {\small\insertinstitute\par}\par\vskip1em
    \par\vskip2em
    {\scriptsize\insertdate}\par\vskip2em
    \inserttitlegraphic
  \end{center}
  \vfill
}


% Display a slide before the current section with overview inf
\AtBeginSection[]
{%
   \begin{frame}
       \frametitle{Overview}
       \tableofcontents[currentsection,hideothersubsections]
   \end{frame}
}

\definecolor{mycolour}{HTML}{A52A2A}

\setbeamercolor*{item}{fg=mycolour}
\setbeamercolor{itemize subitem}{fg=mycolour}

\setbeamerfont{title like}{shape=\scshape}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{shape=\scshape}
\setbeamerfont{section in head/foot}{shape=\scshape,size=\tiny}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} % hide bottom nav buttons
\setbeamercovered{transparent} % don't hide strip-teased bullet points

\setbeamercolor{upper separation line head}{bg=mycolour} 
\setbeamercolor{upper separation line foot}{bg=mycolour} 

\setbeamercolor{lower separation line head}{bg=mycolour} 
\setbeamercolor{lower separation line foot}{bg=mycolour} 
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=black,bg=white} 
\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=red} 
\setbeamercolor{example text}{fg=black} 
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=black} 
 
\setbeamercolor{palette tertiary}{fg=black,bg=black!10} 
\setbeamercolor{palette quaternary}{fg=black,bg=black!10} 

\mode<all>
```

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{mystyle}

\title[Testing-short]{Testing}
\author{M. Tamer \"Ozsu}
\institute{University of Waterloo}

\begin{document}
{
    \frame{\titlepage}
}
  \begin{frame}
   \frametitle{We are testing...}
    It's working!
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]